# Right clicking in a pytest testcase within Pycharm says "Run pytest(1)" instead of "Run testcase-name.py"

Tags: pycharm

Usually when right-clicking inside a single testcase inside  a testcases file we can Run or Debug the testcase.  This is not working anymore for me: it is saying

> Run pytest (1)

[image: Run pytest(1)]

Why would this be happening and is there a fix?

Comment: Go to `Settings` `>` `Tools` `>` `Python Integrated Tools` and see if the `Default test runner` is set to pytest and not autodetect... Another possible reason I see for having the one `1` after the test name instead of the function name is that PyCharm created a temporary "run configuration". Try deleting all the temporary test configurations and check if the run config [templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#createExplicitly) are clean, afterwards clear cache...

Comment: @bad_coder  Those are great suggestions. Please make it an answer.  btw the `Default test runner` is already `pytest` . But it's informative to check on it

Comment: This has happened to me before and I'm not sure how I solved it... I can't reproduce it now so I can't answer, I guess last time I tried everything I could think of until something worked. PyCharm also saves test results in temporary user directories (I'm guessing it might interact with the test configuration file?) - but those IDE behaviors aren't fully documented (I think?) so I've gone with just executing pytest on the command line (using a run configuration when I need the debugger) and only rely on PyCharm for showing coverage results.

Comment: To make it work, I had to go into the project structure (in the Settings > Project > Project Structure) and mark test folder as "Tests"